# How to limit total no of rows in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I want a table maximum rows to 100, If i add 101 row to that table, the 1 row should delete automatically. likewise i just want table total row count to 100, delete order should be FIFO.
Is there any direct MySQL function for that?

Comment: Try to use `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: Hi, check here for the answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622326/how-do-you-make-a-threshold-or-limit-mysql-table?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Use BEFORE INSERT trigger for this.

Below, I kept limit of 25, set according to your need.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM table1;
  IF @cnt >= 25 THEN
    CALL sth(); -- raise an error
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can a simple trigger like below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Deleter AFTER INSERT on YourTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    Delete from yourTable where ID = (Select MIN(id) from yourTable);
END;
```

Same as :
[How do you make a threshold or limit mysql table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622326/how-do-you-make-a-threshold-or-limit-mysql-table?rq=1)